# Reuse query for both count and search in Nest ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Is there a means to reuse a fluent query for both a Client.Search and a Client.Count in ElasticSearch via Nest?

Here is the start of a snippet defining a search fluent definition.

```
 System.Func<SearchDescriptor<Documents.City>, ISearchRequest> x = s => 
 s.Index(IndexNames.Cities).From(0)
   .Size(100)
   .Query(q => q.Bool(.....
```

The change for count would be SearchDescriptor -> CountDescriptor and ISearchRequest -> ICountRequest. It appears that the query needs to be written twice as the fluent markup will not compile without upfront knowledge of the types at play.

The essential question is, are there any neat maintainable methods for using a Nest query to execute both Search and Count requests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of reusing search part, try to do it with query:

```
Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<T>, QueryContainer> query =
    q => q.MatchAll();

var searchResponse = await ElasticClient().SearchAsync<T>(s => s
    .Query(query));

var countResponse = await ElasticClient().CountAsync<T>(s => s.Query(query));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you - As a note to other readers you also need to remove the specifying of the index, the from value and the size value from the query definition and call them as extensions on the query execution e.g. s => s.Query(query).From(0).Size(100)....